# Misspelled sematic-similarity tag

Tags: bug, tags

I came across the [sematic-similarity](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sematic-similarity) tag. It is seldom used but it should be spelt correctly at least.

Can someone update the tag?

Comment: done - updates may take a few days to show on all questions